# Excluding User's Input Value from Output

Tags: c, loops

Writing a c program where the objective is to get the user's input a number of times, and when the user has input a specific age, the loop stops and outputs the average, smallest and largest of all the values the user just input; however, when determining the largest/smallest/average of the ages, the program *must* ignore the age that stops the while loop. I am only able to use a single loop. The only issue I am having is with the output. It is not ignoring the specific age and giving me wonky numbers. Here is a piece of my coding:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int age, avAge, minAge, maxAge, sum;
 sum = 0;
//here is where I get the user input
    while (age != -1){
              printf("Please enter age: \n");
              scanf("%d", &age);
//here is where I try to calculate the average
              sum += age;
              avAge = sum / age;
//here is where I placed restrictions on the ages the user can input
              if (age >= 0 && age <= 100)
                   printf("Nice try!\n");
//here is where I try to get the largest/smallest in order
              if (age < minAge)
                   minAge = age;
              if (age > maxAge)
                   maxAge = age;

//here is where I output if the user inputs a 0
              else ( age == -1){
              printf("Smallest: %d\n", minAge);  
              printf("Largest: %d\n", maxAge);
              printf("Average: %d\n", avAge)

  return 0;
  }
```

Please forgive my coding format, I'm on my phone since I'm running an uninstalled ubuntu on my computer. I just want an idea of what I should use to keep the program from using the 0 as the minAge. Since I can only use one loop, my options are limited I think. Please keep in mind I'm very new at c so I apologize for any ignorance on my part. Thank you.

Comment: you've got the wrong logic for average age... `avAge = sum of all ages / total number of ages`

Comment: It's very difficult to assess incomplete code. Please provide a [mcve] including exact input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: `if (age >= 0 && age <= 100)` is suspicious, surely that's meant to be `if (age < 0 && age >= 100)` ?

Comment: @George ... Age is less than or equal to 0 and age is greater than or equal to 100? Actually had a lot of trouble with those, are they inverted or counterintuitive in C programming?

Comment: @Kaylum Like I said, I'm on my phone but I'll see what I can do. Not sure what you expect me to write for expected output since it doesn't matter. They input -1, it prints out the data. They input anything from 0 - 100 (need to edit my code), they get a "Nice try!" Since it isn't the -1, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JoT `>=` means greater than or equal to, also `else ( age == 0){`, `(age ==0)` is redundant, I guess it should be `else if ( age == 0){`. Also it will be easier to give a full answer if you include your initialisation in your q, as there could be other mistakes, i.e initialising `minAge` to 0.

Comment: " It is not ignoring the specific age and giving me wonky numbers". That's what we expect you to tell us exactly. What input did you test and what was the "wonky" output you got? And please do provide a MCVE. If you are on a phone and can't do that then wait until you can before posting the question.

Comment: @George I edited for you guys to give my full coding. And every time I put else if, ubuntu gave me an error message saying "Expected '(' after if"

Comment: @kaylum I appreciate it, but that's not my issue. It's like that on my computer, I just forgot to add it. My issue is how to ignore user input of -1 so it doesn't show up as the minimum value.

Comment: `age`, `minAge` and `maxAge` are all used whilst uninitialised.

Comment: @JoT initialize every variable before the loop starts, for eg largest=-1, and min = 1e9.

Comment: I didn't know I had to initialize every variable if the user was giving the information.

Comment: That's why we insist on an MCVE. do you undertand that now? Even one character can significantly change the complexion of a program.

Comment: @JoT the users only giving information about `age`

Comment: I JUST edited so it's the full and complete code. What you see is what you get folks. Wish someone would actually answer my question.

Comment: @JoT Nope. That code won't compile as such. Copy-paste your code that _at least compiles_.

Comment: @Cool Guy Well mine did on my computer. So I don't know what to tell you. I'm using ubuntu. Thank you, George, I know that. That's all I want.

Comment: We told you. Using uninitialised variables results in undefined behaviour. Is that not clear? At least try init the vars and re-test.

Comment: @JoT Nope. It certainly didn't. Try copy-pasting the code posted here and compile it. The compiler will give out errors for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an infinite loop makes some level of sense here, I've moved your print result statements out of the loop so they will still only execute once the user is done inputting age s. I've also corrected `if (age >= 0 && age <= 100)` to `if (age < -1 && age > 100)` and correctly initialised all variables before use with some added comments, if you've any further questions just drop a comment :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h> // for INT_MAX 
int main(void) 
{
    int age, avAge = 0, minAge = INT_MAX, maxAge = 0, sum = 0, avgCounter = 1; // avgCounter is the amount of times the loop has ran

    while( 1 ) //infinite loop broken if age == -1
    {
        printf("Please enter age: \n");
        scanf("%d", &age);

        if( age == -1 )
            break;   // exit loop
        else if (age < -1 && age > 100)
           printf("Nice try!\n"); // could add continue here in order to not skew the min/max and average age variables.
        else if (age < minAge)
           minAge = age;
        else if (age > maxAge)
           maxAge = age;
        sum += age;
        avAge = sum / avgCounter;
        avgCounter++;
    } 

    printf("Smallest: %d\n", minAge == INT_MAX? 0 : minAge); // incase the user enters -1 straight away  
    printf("Largest: %d\n", maxAge);
    printf("Average: %d\n", avAge);
}
```

NOTE: The actual reason for seeing "wonky numbers" is probably due to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) thanks to uninitialised variables, you must always make sure they are initialised before attempting to read/use them.

Comment: YOU DID IT. That's awesome. I actually do have a few questions: (1) How do you know when to use int main() and int main (void). I've seen the book/websites do both and they don't explain it. (2)Also, why did you set the avgCounter to 1? (3)Why did you put the 1 in the while ()? I understand it's to break the infinite loop, so would the reasoning behind the logic of this working is because it's the abs value of -1? I'm just trying to understand how it works. (4)When you do the avgCounter++, is that incrementing it like in java? (5)Why did you include <limits.h>? What is its purpose?

Comment: this is actually really great. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, I assumed that because it was a variable given by user input, the user would initialize it by inputting the number. Stupid, I know. Thank you for correcting me. Thank you for being nice.

Comment: (1) Normally I wouldn't care, it's just what my editor defaults to although in practice it's to prevent any arguments being passed when `main` is invoked. (2) To prevent division by 0. (3) `while(1)` is an idiomatic way to create an infinite loop as `1` is true and so the "condition" in `while(condition)` is always true. (4) Yes! (5) So I can use the `INT_MAX` macro. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit :
There are too many small errors in you current code both logical and syntax related. 
The below code works as expected by your requirement.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(){
 int age, avAge, minAge, maxAge, sum;
 minAge = 100000 ; // some very large number
 maxAge = -1;   // initailize with min possible age
 sum = 0;
 int iteration = 0 ; // no. of times the loops run with valid input from user
    do{
              printf("Please enter age: , -1 to quit \n");
              scanf("%d", &age);

              if (age >= 0 && age <= 100) {
                   printf("Nice try!\n");
                   iteration ++; 
                   sum += age;
                   avAge = sum / age;   

                 if (age < minAge)
                   minAge = age;

                 if (age > maxAge)
                   maxAge = age;
              }
              else {
                printf("Smallest: %d\n", minAge);  
                printf("Largest: %d\n", maxAge);
                printf("Average: %d\n", avAge);
                break ;
              }     
    }
    while( age > 0 && age <= 100) ;

    return 0;
  }
```

Working [example](http://ideone.com/Cgnees) on ideone.

Comment: I tried this exact thing and it just kept looping and wouldn't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming valid age is in the range `(0, 100]`, here is an implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int age, minAge, maxAge, sum, avAge;
    sum = 0;
    int i = 0;     // counts the number of ages read

    printf("Please enter age: ");
    while (scanf("%d", &age)) {
        // if age is in range (0, 100], consider valid
        //   and invalid otherwise
        if (age > 0 && age <= 100) {
            // calculate sum
            sum += age;

            // if this is the first loop round (i == 0), initialize
            //   both minAge & maxAge to 'age', since they
            //   don't yet have a valid value
            if (i == 0) {
                minAge = age;
                maxAge = age;
                ++i;
            } else {
                if (age < minAge) {
                    minAge = age;
                }
                if (age > maxAge) {
                    maxAge = age;
                }
                ++i;
            }
        } else if (age == 0) {
            // if age is zero, break/exit loop
            // zero can be changed to any invalid value (eg. -1)
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Nice try!\n");
        }
        printf("Please enter age: ");
    }

    // calculate average (outside loop)
    // average = sum / number of ages read
    avAge = sum / i;

    // print summary
    printf("Smallest: %d\n", minAge);
    printf("Largest: %d\n", maxAge);
    printf("Average: %d\n", avAge);

    return 0;
}
```